# Gradle - How to get task output from subproject

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm new to Gradle. I have a sample project structure like this:

```
rootA/
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── subA
    └── build.gradle
```

In `subA` project, there is a task, let call, `goInsideSubA()` and this task can return a **string**  (something like) *"this is inside subA project"*

edit: here is my sample context:

```
//subA/build.gradle:

task goInsideSubA() {
    def string = "this is inside subA project"
}
```

```
// rootA/build.gradle

task showInsideSubA() {
    doLast {
        // how can I get the string from :subA:goInsideSubA task here
    }
}
```

```
// settings.gradle

include ':subA'
```

My question is how can I get that **string** *"this is inside subA project"* for the task `showInsideSubA()` in `rootA` project to reuse?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _"the task can return a string"_? Tasks have outputs and these outputs are usually files. Functions return stuff. Can you show what your task looks like.

Comment: Hi @smac89, I just edit the question to add more context

Comment: I'd recommend you look into task outputs. Every task has some sort of output, but I've only used that feature of tasks for generating files or writing to files. I'm not near a computer now to try if one can set a string as an output, but that's something you can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, by using "task properties":

```
//subA/build.gradle:

task goInsideSubA() {
    ext {
        myString = "this is inside subA project"
    }
}
```

```
// rootA/build.gradle

task showInsideSubA() {
    doLast {
        println tasks.getByPath(':subA:goInsideSubA').myString
    }
}
```

```
// settings.gradle

include ':subA'
```

**result:**

```sh
$ gradle -q showInsideSubA
> this is inside subA project
```